# How to solve problem with list's constructor of static function in Java?

Tags: java, list, static

I have problem with putting values to my list in static switch. I have seen this can be easier done with String[] but for educational reasons please see my logical code to help me see where the problem is.
Bulding a String of this list is so easy, surely the problems is somewhere with filling my list with data but still can't see how to solve it.
When I try to print data nothing shows every time:(

```
package Loop2_hospital;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Hospital {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Patient> listToDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean exit = false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("0 - wyjście z programu, 1 - dopisanie pacjenta, 2 - wyświetlenie listy zapisanych pacjentów.");
            int nr = in.nextInt();
            isExit(listToDisplay, nr, exit);
        } while (exit != true);
    }

    public static void isExit(List<Patient> listToDisplay, int nr, boolean exit) {
        int actualPatientsNumber = 0;
        int MaxPatientsAmount = 10;
        Hospital ref3 = new Hospital();
        Patient patient = new Patient();

        switch (nr) {
            case 0:
                exit = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Podaj imię pacjenta ");
                String name = in2.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko pacjenta");
                String secondName = in2.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Podaj PESEL pacjenta");
                int PEELER = in2.nextInt();
                if (actualPatientsNumber < MaxPatientsAmount){
                    actualPatientsNumber++;
                    Patient tmp = new Patient(name, secondName, PEELER);
                listToDisplay.add((tmp));}
                break;
            case 2:
                display(listToDisplay);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Podaj właściwy nr przy wyborze operacji");
                break;
        }

    }
    public static void display(List<Patient> listToDisplay) {
        if(listToDisplay != null){
            StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();
            for (Patient one : listToDisplay){
                words.append(one);
            }
            System.out.println(words);

        }
//        final String d = listToDisplay.toString();
//        System.out.println(d);
//        Stream.of(listToDisplay).peek(System.out::println);
//        System.out.println("Zapisani pacjenci: ");

//        for (int i = 0; i < actualPatientsNumber; i++) {
//            System.out.println(listToDisplay.get(i).getName() + " " + listToDisplay.get(i).getSecondName() + " nr PESEL: " + listToDisplay.get(i).getPEEL_NR());
    }
}
```

```
package Loop2_hospital;

public class Patient {
    String name;
    String secondName;
    int PEELER;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public int getPEEL_NR() {
        return PEELER;
    }

    public void setPEEL_NR(int PEEL_NR) {
        this.PEELER = PEEL_NR;
    }

    public Patient() {}

    public Patient(String name, String secondName, int PEELER) {
        this.name = name;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.PEELER = PEELER;
    }
}
```

---

I tried following the suggestions given in the comments, but it's still not working.

```
package Loop2_hospital;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hospital {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Patient> listToDisplay = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean exit = false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("0 - wyjście z programu, 1 - dopisanie pacjenta, 2 - wyświetlenie listy zapisanych pacjentów.");
            int nr = in.nextInt();
            if (!Objects.equals(nr, 0)){
            isExit(listToDisplay, nr, exit);}
            else exit = true;
        } while (exit != true);
}

    public static boolean isExit(List<Patient> listToDisplay, int nr, boolean exit) {
        int actualPatientsNumber = 0;
        int MaxPatientsAmount = 10;
        Hospital ref3 = new Hospital();
        Patient patient = new Patient();

        switch (nr) {
            case 0:
                return true;
            case 1:
                Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Podaj imię pacjenta ");
                String name = in2.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Podaj nazwisko pacjenta");
                String secondName = in2.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Podaj PESEL pacjenta");
                int PEELER = in2.nextInt();
                if (actualPatientsNumber < MaxPatientsAmount){
                    actualPatientsNumber++;
                    Patient tmp = new Patient(name, secondName, PEELER);
                listToDisplay.add((tmp));}
                break;
            case 2:
                display(listToDisplay);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Podaj właściwy nr przy wyborze operacji");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void display(List<Patient> listToDisplay) {
        if(listToDisplay != null){
            StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();
            for (Patient one : listToDisplay){
                words.append(one);
            }
            System.out.println(words);

        }
//        final String d = listToDisplay.toString();
//        System.out.println(d);
//        Stream.of(listToDisplay).peek(System.out::println);
//        System.out.println("Zapisani pacjenci: ");

//        for (int i = 0; i < actualPatientsNumber; i++) {
//            System.out.println(listToDisplay.get(i).getName() + " " + listToDisplay.get(i).getSecondName() + " nr PESEL: " + listToDisplay.get(i).getPEEL_NR());
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, your `do...while` loop executes only once because you never set `exit` to `true`

Comment: Oh, now I see. Java is not pass-by-reference. Changing `exit` inside `isExit` won't do anything to `main`'s `exit`. Have `isExit` return it instead, so you can check the return value inside `main`.

Comment: I rolled back your edit and added it at the bottom of the old post. Please don't change your post after people have started answering/commenting. It makes those answer seem wrong confusing. Instead you should do as I did and add your other attempts to the bottom.

Comment: By the way, you're still doing nothing with what `isExit` returns. You should do something like `exit = isExit(listToDisplay, nr, exit);` (and remove `exit` as a parameter for that method, since it's useless)

Comment: Ok, thanks for showing me mistakes in using these references, it will benefit me in the future. I used getters, setters and then whole Patent object by reference as a parameter to fill my list - works